# VS2022 - matching outside brace are not marked in javascript

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Visual studio 2022 - I have just installed VS2022 and noticed that outside braces (some nested elements inside) are no longer marked, as it was before.
Example:

[image]

But it is still working on non-nested brackets:

[image]

And idea why is this happening?

**Edit, october 2023: problem still persists in the latest version of visual studio:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit).
Current
Version 17.6.3**

Comment: The bug is showing back again in version 4.8.09037. Did you find a solution to the issue? @FrenkyB

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No, no solution for now. Same thing happening on october 2023 (see my edit info).

Comment: issue still showing on 17.8.2 update

Comment: I've just found it highlights braces which don't actually match. Worth knowing when debugging! 17.8.2

Answer (score 3):

Same issue for me, it stopped work from update to version 4.8.04084 (VS2022 17.4.4). It's a bug in visual studio, before that version it worked normally. Also when braces matching works, in js file is not applied my own set color of highlight.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No, but with new updates it's much better.

Comment: Same here version 17.4.4.....

Comment: @Euan Gordon the issue is showing in the new update too 17.7.5

Comment: @Euan Gordon I opened a ticket on Microsft Developer Community [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Highlighting-open-curly-brace-no-long-hi/10494714?f=&type=question+OR+problem+OR+idea&type=question+OR+problem+OR+idea&c=&redirect=search%2Fsearch&sort=relevance&q=karel+zikmund&viewtype=all)